# Fourier transforms of distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I am reading a proof claiming that every partial differential operator $P(D)$ has a fundamental solution $E$. It says that "if we have a distribution $u$ on $R^n$ with $u(P(D)\phi)=\phi(0)$ for $\phi\in\mathscr{D}$, then the distribution $E=\check{u}$ satisfies the definition of a fundamental solution."

Perhaps I am being dense at the moment, but I really don't see how this makes sense, namely why $\check{u}$ (inverse Fourier transform) is even defined for a distribution. After all the inverse Fourier transform does not map $\mathscr{D}$ into itself. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Possibly the author really meant _tempered_ distribution.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am coming to think that this is really a mistake in the book. I am almost certain now. But luckily I found a way to repair the proof, and even make it simpler.

Comment: I stopped by the office. There's definitely something wrong with the proof in the book. A line or so later you see $\check\phi(0)=\phi(0)$. (I'm out of practice on those things - in fact you can just take $E=P(-D)u$, right?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think the most natural way to view this proof is as follows: by definition $P(D)E(\phi)=E(P(-D)\phi)$. We want this to be equal to $\phi(0)$, in other words we consider the assignment $P(-D)\phi\mapsto\phi(0)$. So in the end we end up replacing $P(D)$ by $P(-D)$ in the previous parts of the proof. (This is also the way it is written down elsewhere.) No fourier transform required. This part of the proof is just weird. But I think the rest is correct, so it isn't that bad.